# Problem with boot, grub-repair doesn't help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, 14.10, grub-efi

I want to install Ubuntu 14.10 (64bit) and I already have original Windows 8.1.

I turned off secureboot in bios, and fastboot in windows.

Installing ubuntu it's no problem but I don't see the grub after the install.

I tried `boot-repair` from `liveusb`. it found the EFI partition but has some problems. This is my log:

[HERE LOG](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8884024/)

[My computer (I cant find in english)](http://www.toshiba.pl/laptops/satellite/satellite-nb10-a/satellite-nb10t-a-103/)

Answer (score 1):

I just had a fight with my Sony Vaio, UEFI Bios and RAID0 SSD..hehe, I won :)

You have to run Ubuntu again from Live Disk and get Grub Boot Repair via terminal.

Next install your boot-loader on the same disk/partition where your Ubuntu installation is.

It has to work 100%.

Please report here to confirm it, thank you!

Comment: P.S. DONT TOUCH THE /dev/sda2 - EFI System partition and 
/dev/sda3  Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows).

sda2 is for your "bios" and sda3 contains Win8 boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB was installed in the right partition?

If was, check this link, can help u: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Secure Boot isn't necessary as Ubuntu, since 13.10 release, provides an efi partition to "coexist peacefully" with Windows.

During setup you've choice the manual partitioning or the automated installation alongside Windows 8 (if detected)?

The log file seems healthy, but you did a madness by installing the efi partition in another hard disk! Surely you did a manual partitioning... wrongly.

And you installed the bootloader (so, the same GRUB) in Ubuntu partition ( *sda8* ) instead of MBR ( *sda* ). Another mistake, but nothing major.

---

You have to redo the Ubuntu setup and choose the manual partitioning.

"Delete" all the partitions related to Ubuntu in both *sda* and *sdb* disks.

Then create the following ones:

**sda7: efi 105 MB** | **sda8: biosgrub 256 MB** (probably less space is required, I don't know) | **sda9: swap 4096 MB** (as your RAM amount) | **sda10: btrfs** (better than ext4) **what you want MB** (I would suggest you at least 10-20 GB).

**Bootloader** in ***sda***... and go peacefully ;)

Comment: bootloader in sda... ? witch number?

Comment: No any number, you have to install them in _sda_. It's better so, don't ask me why, I don't know.

Believe me :)